# Moving Files Via PowerShell to Remote Computers

Tags: powershell

I am currently attempting to move a file from a local destination to remote Pc's on the network. I am hoping to extend this to multiple users however in the mean time I am only trying to move one file to one machine.

The current script I'm using is below

```
# sets the varible for the file location
$file = "c:\Powershell\testfile.txt"

$getcred = Get-Credential 'user'
New-PSDrive -Name Oli -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\uint140\c$ -Credential $using:getcred #\Users\oliverturner\Desktop

# displays the computer names on screen
Get-Content $file | foreach {Copy-Item "C:\Powershell\testfile.txt" -Destination Oli}
```

When I run this however I am receiving the below error

```
The provider does not support the use of credentials. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.
At C:\Powershell\movefile2.ps1:8 char:1
+  <<<< New-PSDrive -Name Oli -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\uint140\c$ -Credential $using:getcred #\Users\oliverturner
\Desktop #-Credential jamesfegan\invateltd.local -Persist
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
```

I have attempted to remove -Credential however and $getcred however I receive

```
New-PSDrive: Drive root "\\uint140\c$" does not exist or it's not a folder
```

Is this an issue with using New-PSDrive or is there another command that would work better?

Comment: If the account who runs the script has sufficient right to all target folders you don't have to care about credentials at all. For copy jobs use robocopy. It is made for ....  And you can make your life easier when you use unc paths instead of drive letters.

Comment: If you are domain administrator, just use: `Copy-Item -Path '\\server1\\c$\\file1.txt' -Destination '\\server2\\c$'`

Comment: Why do you want to use `New-PSDrive` instead of just `Copy-Item -Destination \\uint140\c$`?

Comment: Thanks @Olaf robocopy worked great. Is there a way to add a foreach command to robocopy to send 1 file to multiple destinations?

Comment: Nope. ;-) You would need to do this in your Powershell script then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Sessions stuff
$usr = "Domain\User"
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String <insert pw here>
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$usr",$pw
$session = new-pssession -computername <computer> -credential $cred

# sets the variable for the file location
$file = "c:\Powershell\testfile.txt"
$Dest = "c:\temp"

# Lets copy!
Copy-Item -ToSession $session -Path $File -Destination $Dest
```

Try something like this. It creates a session to the remote server and uses that session to send the file.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Will add a proper explanation when i've a spare moment.

Comment: While casing doesn't really matter in PowerShell, it's good practice to care for, becaus it increases Readability. Pro Tip: Instead of building `PSCredential` objects with `New-Object` and SecureStrings, one can just use [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-5.1). Nevertheless I like your approach.